# Stop executing function after data change (React, useEffect)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, graphql, use-effect

I have a function (`startLoad()`) which is executed every time some of my data changes (i.e. `dataMayChange`).
Within this method i want to execute some GraphQL Queries (i.e. fireQuery1, fireQuery2, ...).
Every time when my dataMayChange changes, i want to stop executing startLoad and execute it again from the beginning. This way i want to prevent the old queries before my dataMayChange has changed to be fired.

Here is my Code:

```
 React.useEffect(() => {   
        startLoad()     
    // eslint-disable-next-line
}, [dataMayChange])

const startLoad = async() => {
  await fireQuery1
  await fireQuery2
  await fireQuery3
  await fireQuery4
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how i can achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is a flag or signal you can provide to `startLoad` to tell it to stop, and a [cleanup callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect) on `useEffect`.

You can do a bespoke flag or signal, or use [`AbortController`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController). Here's an example of the latter but roll-your-own would look quite similar:

```
React.useEffect(() => {   
    const controller = new AbortController();
    startLoad(controller.signal);
    return () => {
        // This function is called when the data is changing and the
        // effect callback is about to be re-run
        controller.abort();
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line
}, [dataMayChange]);

const startLoad = async (signal) => {
    await fireQuery1;
    if (signal.aborted) {
        return;
    }
    await fireQuery2;
    if (signal.aborted) {
        return;
    }
    await fireQuery3;
    if (signal.aborted) {
        return;
    }
    await fireQuery4;
};
```

That's quite repetitive, you probably want to put your actions in an array and loop through it. It's hard to show that given that `fireQuery1` etc. are obviously just conceptual placeholders, but for instance:

```
const startLoad = async (signal) => {
    const tasks = [doThis, doThat, doTheOther, doSomethingElse];
    for (const task of tasks) {
        if (signal.aborted) {
            return;
        }
        await task(); // You can even keep track of its result to pass to the next if relevant, etc.
    }
};
```

If any of those actions involve things (like `fetch`) that support `AbortController`/`AbortSignal`, you can also pass the signal on to those things.

Comment: Thank you alot this seemed to work! :)